# Out parameter inside CONCAT (MySql Stored Procedures)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concatenation

I created a dynamic stored procedure in mysql for "select" job. It works okay. However i cant add an out parameter inside the concat. How can i do that? I tried :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic_select(IN table VARCHAR(50), IN column VARCHAR(50), IN ucolumn VARCHAR(50), OUT total INT)
BEGIN
SET @stmt = CONCAT('SELECT count(*) INTO total FROM ',table,' WHERE ',column,'="',ucolumn,'"');
```

I guess i cant write it like a string since that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [13.5.1 PREPARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html)
>
> ...
>
> - A statement prepared in stored program context cannot refer to stored procedure or function parameters or local variables because
>     they go out of scope when the program ends and would be unavailable
>     were the statement to be executed later outside the program. As a
>     workaround, refer instead to user-defined variables, which also have
>     session scope; see [Section 9.4, "User-Defined Variables"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `dynamic_select`(
  IN `table` VARCHAR(50),
  IN `column` VARCHAR(50),
  IN `ucolumn` VARCHAR(50),
  OUT `total` INT
)
BEGIN
  SET @`stmt` := CONCAT('SELECT 1 INTO @`stmt_total`');
  PREPARE `stmt2` FROM @`stmt`;
  EXECUTE `stmt2`;
  SET `total` := @`stmt_total`;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt2`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b8d2/1)</kbd>

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to see both table and total at he end. It shows me just value of total.

Comment: @jjkk: table and total? Show an example.

Comment: i mean stored procedures returns a table if there is no OUT parameter given in. is there a way to see this table and out parameter in the end. I guess there is no way to do this. Not neccessary for my job though, just asking

Comment: @jjkk: Perhaps something like it [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/048f6/1) can be useful.